# php preg_match_all advice needed for a special case

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have this three strings:

```
72728:[390,1138,1139],12:1234,14:[12],13:12
72728:[390,1138,1139]
12:1234,14:1123
```

the goal is to split the Strings into Pairs of (name:value), while value can be a number or a list.

My regular expression looks like this so far:

```
preg_match_all('/([^:]*\:[^:]*\,|\S*\:\S*$)/',$string,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER)
```

for the first String I get the right result for the second string I don't get a valid result. It cuts of the result like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 72728:[390,1138,
                    [1] => 0
                ) 
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 72728:[390,1138,
                    [1] => 0
                )  
        )   
)
```

Why is this the case? I am ready to give up and try some ugly other solution...
Or is there even a better solution where I use the regex for some pre processing?

Comment: That almost appears to be json. You could probably just put curly braces around it and json_decode each line.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn are you sure? like this: `print_r(json_decode("{".$string."}"), true);` - because this didn't work ...

Comment: You would need to process each line separately or replace the newlines with a comma.

Comment: Just to show you that it's a bad idea: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=995856 modify it to JSON and use a json parser

Comment: When I was testing around, json_decode failed simply because json_decode requires the keys to be enclosed with double quotes or else it is malformed. Perhaps a different json parser would work or it could be re-formatted.

Comment: @alfasin I am sorry, the values come as they are. I have no influence on them...

Comment: why did somebody -1 this question? You shell provide an explanation, due to the guide lines.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question but I think that trying to parse a context-free language with regex is such a bad idea which probably caused someone to downvote. As for your other comment, even if you don't 'control' the input you can pre-process it (add quotes around the keys etc) and then use a JSON parser.

Comment: @alfasin well, when I pre-process it ... I gues I would be able to split up the whole structure anyway ... or in which way would I archive that - maybe I am a bit slow on the uptake at the moment - so bring me there please.

Comment: @helle I don't know how else to say it... you can't parse a context-free language with regex.

Comment: I guess I got it now and for everybody coming by, check my comment to the accepted answer, where I recommend the solution with the json pre-processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you need to test the case of a list first to avoid the comma problem:

```
$pattern = '~[^\n:,]+:(?:\[[^]]+]|[^,\s]+)~';
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

Jonathan Kuhn approach is interesting too *(depending of what you have to do after)*. If your values are only integers, you can write:

```
$str = '{' . strtr($str, PHP_EOL, ',' ) . '}';
$str = preg_replace('~[0-9]+~', '"$0"', $str);
$res = json_decode($str, true);
print_r($res);
```

Comment: both ways are great and worked very well. due to the comments to my question I recommend the second solution!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
(\d+):(\d+|\[[^]]+\])
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/oB0aI4

PHP:

```
$string = '72728:[390,1138,1139],12:1234,14:[12],13:12';

preg_match_all('/(\d+):(\d+|\[[^]]+\])/',$string,$matches,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(21) "72728:[390,1138,1139]"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "12:1234"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "14:[12]"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "13:12"
}
```